# When binding to vfio-pci for PCI Passthrough, I lose my ssh connection. How can I overcome this?

Tags: drivers, pci, kubernetes

I am going through [this KubeVirt](https://kubevirt.io/user-guide/virtual_machines/host-devices/) article on PCI Passthrough. When I get to the step that unbinds the Ethernet controller from the `igb` driver, I lose my ssh connection.

```
echo 0000:02:00.3 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/igb/unbind
echo "vfio-pci" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:02\:00.3/driver_override
echo 0000:02:00.3 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind
```

Is it possible to do this over ssh?

If not, I'll have to use two separate NICs. When I type this into the server's keyboard, I am unable to connect to the box. Does the newly bound driver need to get a new DHCP lease?

Comment: Is there a reason  you can't put that in a script and run the script with `./script.sh &` so the SSH connection doesn't need to stay up?

Comment: No, and also eventually I'm going to do this inside a kubernetes controller so it doesn't matter. Also after talking to my team, we are going to enforce not doing passthrough on the management NIC anyway.